# Edit CUPS Filter source file to produce "beep" tone before printing

Tags: c, printing, thermal-printer, escpos

I have a Rongta RP326 printer which supports ESC/POS, it literally says that on the bottom of the printer.

I have this printer connected to a Raspberry Pi Model 4B.

The manufacturer of this receipt printer unfortunately does not have ARM linux drivers... but I was able to find this driver that works great: https://github.com/klirichek/zj-58 it has build instructions so though I don't know C and how programs are usually compiled...I was able to follow the instructions and get it compiled and working.

The paper cutting works fine (I haven't tested drawer because I don't have one but it might work fine since I can see printer options for it in printer properties)

What doesn't work is the "beep" that comes through whenever a print job is about to happen on the printer. This printer does support the beep because on Windows and MacOS it works just fine.

Through research I was able to find the ESC/POS command that needs to be sent to the printer for the beep.

However, **I do not know any C programming** so I'm literally stuck as to what to do and how to bring that ESC/POS command over to C code.

- Here is the source file for the filter with the C code that looks to control what the printer does: https://github.com/klirichek/zj-58/blob/master/rastertozj.c
- Here is a comment on a thread from an unrelated library where the user had my same line of receipt printer and was able to get it to beep by sending a ESC/POS command: https://github.com/mike42/escpos-php/issues/142#issuecomment-231601204
- Here is EPSON's reference for sending a beep: https://www.epson-biz.com/modules/ref_escpos/index.php?content_id=212
- Here is a link I found while searching that has command sets for Rongta printers: https://forum.sambapos.com/uploads/default/original/3X/e/7/e72c4636329d5a4b4a81fcc0606a720029f6541e.pdf

I have stumbled across the resources but unfortunately the block in the road is that I do not know C and I do not know the first step to taking what I'm seeing in the documentation links and transferring it to the filer's source file.

I tried editing the code to add the following lines:

```
static void sendBeep(int n, int t) {
  if (n >= 1 && n <= 9 && t >= 1 && t <= 9) {
    char beepCommand[] = "\x1B\x42";
    beepCommand[2] = n + '0'; // Convert n to ASCII
    beepCommand[3] = t + '0'; // Convert t to ASCII
    SendCommand(beepCommand);
  }
}
```

Then inside the "setupJob()" function, I added a line with `sendBeep(3, 5);`

That didn't work. I later realized that this was for changing the beep tone which I fed from the Rongta RP80 command set doc.

I then tried instead to use the following code:

```
static void soundBuzzer(int n, int c, int t) {
  if (n >= 0 && n <= 9 && c >= 1 && c <= 9 && t >= 0 && t <= 9) {
    // ESC/POS command to sound the buzzer
    char buzzerCommand[] = "\x1b\x28\x41\x04\x00\x30";
    buzzerCommand[6] = n + '0'; // Convert n to ASCII
    buzzerCommand[7] = c + '0'; // Convert c to ASCII
    buzzerCommand[8] = t + '0'; // Convert t to ASCII
    SendCommand(buzzerCommand);
  }
}
```

And added `soundBuzzer(4, 3, 1);` inside the `setupJob()` function body:

```
void setupJob() {
  SendCommand(escInit);
  if (settings.CashDrawer1 == 1)
    CashDrawerEject(0,settings.CashDrawer1On,settings.CashDrawer1Off);
  if (settings.CashDrawer2 == 1)
    CashDrawerEject(1, settings.CashDrawer2On, settings.CashDrawer2Off);  
  
  soundBuzzer(4, 3, 1);
}
```

That didn't make the beep sound either. Each time I've been deleting the filter from CUPS `/usr/lib/cups/filter`, recompiling it with the updated source, and then adding it back to the directory `/usr/lib/cups/filter` but can't get any beep still.

Any help in understanding this and getting it to work would be greatly appreciated

P.S I have posted an issue on the github repo for the driver I'm using but the repo seems to be abandoned though it still works fine: https://github.com/klirichek/zj-58/issues/49

Comment: Unfortunately, "I want somebody else to do my work for me" is not a suitable topic for Stack Overflow. Try to hire a Linux freelancer on one of the sites where that is acceptable.

Comment: @tripleee Such an original comment, obviously I expected it. I'm not expecting someone else to do my work for me. I'm asking for assistance in understanding and getting closer to my end goal. If you can't assist and would rather gatekeep, then this question is not for you. I've helped other devs many times on StackOverflow who are in unfamiliar territory and just don't know how to move forward. Please try to be kinder to your fellow devs and stop this toxic sort of thinking on StackOverflow.

Comment: Adding your attempt is a significant improvement; thanks for that. Rejecting questions which are too broad or unclear etc is not "toxic"; it is an essential part of the curation effort that ensures that our content is of high quality.

Comment: Some printers share the same command for the buzzer function and other functions (for example, cash drawer control), and switch between modes depending on the hardware settings. Please check the specifications or manuals, or contact your vendor or reseller, to see if your printer has such a toggle feature.